# Multivariate Analysis of Ecological Data: Procrustes analyses or GLM?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, ecology, procrustes-analysis

I have a dataset containing 6 variables (vegetation cover in percent) and the number of species found in 30 areas. 
I would like to test if the different vegetation covers explain species richness.

Question: What kind of statistical approach is suitable to analyse this dataset?

GLMs would be nice, but I see the problem that the variables are not independent of each other. Also, there are some missing values for some variables in some catchments. Another possibility seems to be a Procrustes analyses, but I have no experience with that.

The dataset:

```
 Area,% Wetlands,% Forest,% Shrubland,% Grassland,% Cropland,% Other,Species
    1,54.4272,9.6048,6.9276,15.8056,5.3268,7.908,52
    2,0.2576,8.234,1.5456,74.5292,6.9828,8.4508,10
    3,32.3104,9.2092,12.9812,30.3508,5.3728,9.7756,13
    4,0.0828,1.3984,3.404,77.1972,7.5624,10.3552,45
    5,0.1104,2.8704,5.198,52.8908,30.4336,8.4968,19
    6,12.4476,7.6176,3.4684,43.0744,24.9412,8.4508,43
    7,0,2.9256,0.5704,78.798,9.4208,8.2852,58
    8,1.1224,0.9476,1.0488,81.7052,0.3312,14.8448,42
    9,22.4296,28.566,11.454,12.052,17.4892,8.0092,85
    10,1.6376,44.3348,2.99,39.4036,1.518,10.116,35
    11,2.2816,7.0748,6.3204,62.882,9.5036,11.9376,74
    12,0.9568,2.438,0.8464,85.9464,0.0276,9.7848,26
    13,66.7092,0.1932,2.3276,12.374,10.396,8,59
    14,0.0092,4.2136,1.8584,84.456,0.3496,9.1132,23
    15,0.828,8.5836,2.8152,78.936,0.0736,8.7636,64
    16,39.0172,2.5024,1.8952,47.6928,0.2024,8.69,52
    17,0,11.8772,0.3772,71.7692,0,15.9764,35
    18,21.1876,4.8668,7.176,54.2432,4.4068,8.1196,54
    19,15.3272,1.2512,11.3528,57.2424,5.9892,8.8372,65
    20,69.4048,5.8512,12.282,4.1032,0.368,7.9908,74
    21,17.8848,3.3212,7.6912,61.2904,1.8124,8,71
    22,2.0884,11.5368,4.8208,71.5576,1.702,8.2944,34
    23,80.6288,0.0644,0.9476,8.8596,1.472,8.0276,58
    24,1.518,1.2696,0.1104,87.5472,1.5364,8.0184,34
    25,1.4444,12.328,0.0828,77.9976,0,8.1472,20
    26,0,0.3404,0,91.4848,0.1288,8.046,64
    27,1.4628,0.8188,0.414,86.2224,0.0276,11.0544,87
    28,34.9324,8.9976,2.3828,44.7856,0,8.9016,17
    29,0.8464,11.3988,1.656,76.3692,1.1592,8.5704,43
    30,1.9044,3.588,1.4996,79.902,0.2024,12.9036,58
```

Comment: I can't see any missing values in the variables in your table

Answer (score 1):

Your data and question are definitely not suitable for Procrustes, since your response variable is univariate not multivariate (species richness). Your problem seems to be suitable for a GLM indeed, with richness as predicted by the covers. As for the problem with the colinearity among the predictor variables, you could easily test that by calculating a Variation Inflation Factor (VIF), in `r` see `usdm::vif`. Here you need a GLM because species richness usually follows a Poisson distribution.